# The effect of index on unique constraint columns

Tags: database, postgresql, multi-index, unique-index

How is the table made?

```
create table market_post
( 
    .
    . 
    .
    d_id  varchar(20) constraint unique_d_id unique,
    .
    . 
    .
);
create index market_post_d_i_219a22_idx on market_post (d_id, is_deleted);
```

It should be noted that above code is DDL of table and i created the indexes and unique constraint when the table was created and was full of data (ALTER....)

Sometimes it allows duplicate value in `d_id` and sometimes it not allows!!

Let's test:

**TEST1**

```
SELECT id,d_id
FROM public.market_post 
WHERE id in (1910764,2584556)
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------
|    id  |   d_id   |is_deleted|
--------------------------------
|1910764 | QYynk1fG | true    |
--------------------------------
|2584556 | gYkgfj_M | true    |
--------------------------------
```

now i want update:

```
UPDATE public.market_post SET d_id = 'gYkgfj_M'WHERE id = 1910764
```

Result:

```
[2022-07-24 10:31:52] 1 row affected in 116 ms
```

OMG! now result is:

```
---------------------
|    id  |   d_id   |
---------------------
|1910764 | gYkgfj_M |
---------------------
|2584556 | gYkgfj_M |
---------------------
```

**interesting point**

```
SELECT id,d_id FROM public.market_post  WHERE d_id='gYkgfj_M'
```

only returnt one row !!!!!!!!

```
---------------------
|    id  |   d_id   |
---------------------
|1910764 | gYkgfj_M |
---------------------
```

**TEST2**

```
SELECT id,d_id
FROM public.market_post 
WHERE id in (191076 , 258455)
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------
|    id  |   d_id   |is_deleted|
--------------------------------
|191076 | SYyFk1fA  |  false    |
--------------------------------
|258455 | fYkDfjbb  |  false     |
--------------------------------
```

now i want update:

```
UPDATE public.market_post SET d_id = 'fYkDfjbb' WHERE id = 191076
```

Result:

```
[23505] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_d_id" 
Detail: Key (d_id)=(fYkDfjbb) already exists.
```

its guarantees that the duplicate value was not found in the rows where `is_deleted=false`

Unique constraint does not work in Postgres?(Of course it should work) Or has the index affected it?

**is this bug?** no , i tested it in new table (in my server and in SQL fiddle) and all of them work truly , and there isn't any bug

But the old table is not work

It should be noted that I created the indexes and  unique constraint when the table was full of data

VAERSION:12

Comment: Why would you *not* disclose your version of Postgres with that question? Anyway, looks like a corrupt index. Run `REINDEX TABLE market_post;` and try again. The reason might be failing hardware (RAM, disk, ...)

Comment: Please create a fiddle that shows this issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Comment: "...But the old table is not work..." -- It's either a corrupt index, or maybe it's a partial index. In the first case, just drop and recreate the index. If you think it's the second case, please include the full index definition, specifically the `WHERE` clause in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ErwinBrandstetter said in the comments, I should have rebuilt the indexes! Apparently, I had fallen into a Postgres bug
After running ‍‍‍‍`REINDEX TABLE market_post;` everything was solved

The hard part was where I had to distinguish values with duplicate IDs and delete one of them! As I said in the question, Postgres returns only one of the records. I took the entire table with the help of pandas and identified the duplicate values and then removed them

After the steps, it was time to `REINDEX`